# How can I know the draggable item was really dropped in specified sortable container in Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

All, I knew we can implement a draggable to a element just simply call the `.draggable` method in jquery ui.
here is an example for it including connect to sortable.

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
            helper : function(){
                   //return something dom.},
            cursor : 'move',
            connectToSortable : '.sortableLayoutSection'});

$(".sortableLayoutSection").sortable({
            appendTo : parent,
            containment : "parent",
            cursor : "pointer",
            placeholder : 'li-placeholder',
            forcePlaceholderSize : false
        });
```

But my question is how can I known the draggable item really drop into the specified container(in this example is element with class named `.sortableLayoutSection`)? thanks.

**Updated**

```
$(".sortableLayoutSection").sortable({
                appendTo : parent,
                containment : "parent",
                cursor : "pointer",
                placeholder : 'li-placeholder',
                forcePlaceholderSize : false,
                receive: function( event, ui ) {alert('ok.got something.')}
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should init your sortable element as droppable element too, while please refer to this:http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop. it has drop event, it means that there is a drag element has been drag in to droppable. so you can write the function to determine what you want to do.

Comment: Hi, OQJF, your answer is good ,I upvote it, but it is not simple enough, please review my answer. thanks.

Comment: I've noticed you answer, though didn't test it, I think it can work well. thank you Joe, nice guy, oblivious, it will help lots of guys.

Comment: sorry buddy, I can't join any chat cuz company policy. anyway fun day.

Comment: There are a lot of chinese friends here .So someone build a chat room for us .you can join it. thanks.

Comment: that's blocked by our company.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257925/jquery-draggable-sortable-how-to-tell-if-item-was-actually-added-to-my-sortab), After I test it , It solve my problem, only drop in the specified container will trigger a event named `receive`,please review my updated content .thanks.